# low speed download from url seed in libtorrent

Tags: libtorrent

We're looking for an advice concerning usage of url seeds. We use libtorrent to distribute our application's build to the customers. For that purpose we use a single torrent tracker and several web servers all distributing the same file.

On the client side there is a C# application that uses a native dll with libtorrent. Right after the torrent file addition all url seeds are added to it using the torrent_handle::add_url_seed. The torrent is auto managed.

The problem is the speed. Despite that in our test environments this setup shows good speed from time to time, our production client downloads from our 8 url seeds with the speed close to zero (50 kb/s max). When we try to download from the same urls with a browser we get server-limited speed (1 Mb/s and more). Attempting to download with a script that simulates libtorrent's request gives the same high speed. Only notable difference between setups is the seed/peer count: production setup has lots of them (> 50), while the test one has only main seed and one url seed.

What can be the reason for such a behaviour? Is there any libtorrent option that can affect this?

Comment: I have the same or a similar issue.
When downloading with wget from the url_seed I get an average download speed of 80 to 110 MiB/s (the median is around 90 MiB/s). wget thus runs roughly at the speed the Ethernet adapaters of my machines allow.
Downloading the same build (from only that url_seed) with libtorrent (libtorrent-rasterbar-1.0.5) I get speeds between 35 and 68 MiB/s (median is around 50 MiB/s).
The file composition of the torrent does not seem to affect the speed greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from Arvid Norberg here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.network.bit-torrent.libtorrent/4631